# Default visual style in Chart.js bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, charts

The doc gives a little example about bar chart:

```
var data = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
        }
    ]
}
```

and then to create the chart using `new Chart(ctx).Bar(data);`

Is it possible to define the **view** separately from the **data** i.e. define `fillColor` and `strokeColor` somewhere else leaving only `data` in `datasets` objects? Assume I want only one set in datasets.

I want to generate the data (labels and values) in back-end, and leave the view details to the front-end.

The official options don't expect this.

---

**Doc:**
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#barChart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in that [chartjs](/questions/tagged/chartjs) does not support those properties as global options.

Fortunately, a quick fix would require you to only change source lines including...

```
data.datasets[i].fillColor
```

...to, for instance:

```
config.fillColor || data.datasets[i].fillColor
```

...resulting in something similar to:

```
ctx.fillStyle = config.fillColor || data.datasets[i].fillColor;
```

The same applies to `strokeColor`.

Then you can either add a `fillColor` property to the global config or include it in datasets.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute options based on ChartJS' options on the server as well, if needbe and pass that as a parameter to

```
new Chart(ctx).Bar(data,options);
```

like

```
new Chart(ctx).Bar(data,{fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)", strokeColor :"rgba(151,187,205,1)",});
```

because ChartJS does a merge of options in

```
function mergeChartConfig(defaults,userDefined){
    var returnObj = {};
    for (var attrname in defaults) { returnObj[attrname] = defaults[attrname]; }
    for (var attrname in userDefined) { returnObj[attrname] = userDefined[attrname]; }
    return returnObj;
}
```

You can edit that to give you the effect you want! https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/Chart.js

Comment: is the merging of options in the official release or just something you wish for? `fillColor` is not described in the official doc in the `options` paragraph

Comment: @cggaurav nice find! Could Bob pull the 'currently set' options from an instantiated chart in order to do his own merge so as not to reset anything already set back to default if he doesn't explicitly set it again?

Comment: Ah, from what I understand, fillColor and strokeColor are properties of ctx and you have to change that by forking ChartJS. ctx.fillStyle = YourfillColor;
ctx.strokeStyle = YourstrokeColor;

Comment: @cggaurav so the second line in your answer won't work? :( because it looks EXACTLY how i'd want to use it

Comment: @BinaryBob So the above will work if you edit ChartJS' code but do submit a feature request at https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues